# Getting different results on Windows Phone 7 Device vs Emulator

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I'm getting different results from the emulator vs what is actually on the device.

I'm making a Linq-to-XML filtering query and the one on the emulator is returning correct results while the device one is return 0 results.

```
var result = (from p in xmlDoc.Descendants("Item")
    where p.Element("Version").Value != "NA" 
          && p.Element("Release").Value != String.Empty
          && DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Subtract(DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(p.Element("Release").Value, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ", cultureInfo)).TotalDays <= 30
          && DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Subtract(DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(p.Element("Release").Value, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ", cultureInfo)).TotalDays > 0
    orderby DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(p.Element("Release").Value, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ssZ", cultureInfo) descending
    group p by p.Element("Id").Value into Items
    select Items).ToList();
```

I've set a breakpoint on both instances and culture is the same.

What gives?

UPDATE:

XML document returned is exactly the same.

Comment: Is the xml document the same? Is the time the same?

Comment: without seeing the document you're parsing and the culture (on both to verify they're the same) it'll be hard to say. What version of the emulator and device firmware are you running? If you're seeing different results/behaviour in different places you need to start by identifying what is different about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me, Windows Phone 7 has automatic date and time set. (Time was correct but date was wrong!) But of course, with no actual SIM Card, the datetime was incorrectly set. Therefore, it is giving me different results.